# .offset returning property of null

Tags: jquery

Not sure why it's returning a `Cannot read property 'top' of null` whenever I click on an A tag from the `.fullWidthBorder` instead of scrolling to it.

NAV

```
    <div class="fullWidthBorder">
    <div class="row show-for-large-up">
                <li class="technology">
<a data-scroll="technology">Technology <span class="navArrow"></span>
</a>
</li>
</div>
</div>
```

BODY

```
<div class="content-block">

    <div class="responsive-container">
        <h1 class="centered" data-scroll="technology" id="technology">&mdash; Technology &mdash;</h1>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('.fullWidthBorder a').on('click', function() {
    var scrollAnchor = $(this).attr('data-scroll'),
        scrollPoint = $('h1[data-anchor="' + scrollAnchor + '"]').offset().top - 28;

    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollPoint
    }, 500);

    return false;
})
```

Comment: Have you debugged the output of `$('h1[data-anchor="' + scrollAnchor + '"]')`? Make sure it's actually finding elements

Comment: Please include your HTML, as well.

Comment: Here is the HTML. It seems like console is finding $('h1[data-anchor="' + scrollAnchor + '"]') just fine...